# Override virtual methods in partial classes that are generated

Tags: linq-to-sql, class, virtual, partial

In my LINQ generate class, I have this method:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Id",
             AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", 
             IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
public int Id
{
    get
    {
        return this._Id;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._Id != value))
        {
            this.OnIdChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();    
            this._Id = value;            
            this.SendPropertyChanged("Id");
            this.OnIdChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

In my coded partial class, I extend from a base class. The base class defines:

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
```

The concept is that I can add the Equals and Hashcode at the base class level, as well as some other functionality at the base class level. The problem is that the generated classes  (from LINQ-to-SQL) do not get an `override` keyword so it doesnt work. If it had `override` I would be all set.

Please suggest on how to complete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the base class `abstract`, and then the Id property becomes

```
public abstract int Id { get; set; }
```

The generated code will implement that abstract property.

Comment: that works great. It requires each subclass to have the value but in our model, they all do.

Answer (score 0):

A partial class is different from overriding a class. With a partial class you're just saying. Ok, i have 1 class but i have splitted the source up over multiple files (mainly for maintainable reasons like splitting the auto generated code from your own code). The C# compiler just merges each part of a partial class together and threats it as 1 class. Ofcourse overriding a class means you create a new class which takes on the characteristics of the base class. That is very different.

Now it's possible but not relatively easy to direct EF of how to generate your code (assuming you are using EF). One option you can do though is to change your base class not to work with the Property Id but a more recognizable (and specifix?) name like 'CompareIdentifier'. With that you can override CompareIdentifier in your derived class for returning the auto generated ID. And ofcourse do all comparison work against CompareIdentifier

Answer (score 0):

I would have created a wrapper class around this.